# Connect LINQDataSource to an In-memory Collection (Generic List)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

So I have an asp.net application that I'm trying to use upgrade. What I want to accomplish is to use the value selected in one Dropdownlist to determine the values shown in a second dropdownlist. To this extent I created the two DDL's and bound them to LINQDataSource objects in the markup. What I figured I'd do is bind the second LinqDatasource to a List(of tablename) list that I create on form Load that way I have the collection in memory and can run LINQ on it client side so I dynamically determine the return set of the datasource and thusly the values in the Dropdownlist.

I saw you can supposedly point your LinqDataSource to a list as long as the list is a property. So I have tried the following but get an error saying it can't find my class.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTitle" runat="server" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="Title"
        DataSourceID="ViolationTitles" Width="203px" >
    </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlChapters" runat="server" 
        DataTextField="FullChapterName" DataValueField="Chapter_Number"
        DataSourceID="ViolationChapters" Width="203px">
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="ViolationTitles" runat="server" 
        ContextTypeName="ARS_LINQ_Connections.ARSDataContext" EntityTypeName="" Select="new (key as Title, it as Violation_Title_Chapters)" 
        TableName="Violation_Title_Chapters" GroupBy="Title">
    </asp:LinqDataSource>

    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="ViolationChapters" runat="server"
    ContextTypeName="Test"  
        EntityTypeName="" 
        TableName="rsViolations" 
        Select='new (Title, Chapter_Number, Chapter_Name, String.Concat(Chapter_Number + ". " + Chapter_Name) as FullChapterName)'>
    </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Code Behind

```
Public Class Test
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Public Property rsViolations As New List(Of Violation_Code)

    Dim arslinq As New ARS_LINQ_Connections.ARSDataContext
    Dim rsTitles As New List(Of Violation_Title_Chapter)

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        rsViolations = (From v In arslinq.Violation_Codes).ToList
        rsTitles = (From t In arslinq.Violation_Title_Chapters).ToList



    End Sub
End Class
```